# How to convince Mathematica that $(-1)^{2/3} = e^{2\pi i /3}$

Tags: complex

I have a list `T` which contains `3 + 4*E^(2*Pi*I/3)`. Yet `MemberQ[ T , 3 + 4*(-1)^(2/3) ]` returns false.

One can check for themselves with `MemberQ[{3 + 4*E^(2*Pi*I/3)}, 3 + 4*(-1)^(2/3)]`. It will return `False`.

How can I tweak this so that the above returns `True`? Am I fumbling some detail regarding the principal branch?

Comment: From the docs Possible Issues section for `MemberQ`: _MemberQ tests for structural matches, not numerical equality_ . You could try this instead: `ContainsAny[T, {3 + 4*(-1)^(2/3)}, SameTest -> Equal]`

Comment: ^ or alternatively, because ContainsAny is a bit slow, you could ComplexExpand your list T and the item before using MemberQ which (fingers crossed) will put them in the same structural form.

Comment: Following the suggestion above:  `lis = {E^(2*Pi*I/3),  (-1)^(2/3  )} //ComplexExpand //InputForm`

`(* {-1/2 + (I/2)*Sqrt[3], -1/2 + (I/2)*Sqrt[3]} *)`

Comment: `Or @@ (Equal[#, 3 + 4*(-1)^(2/3)] & /@ T)`

Comment: @flinty ComplexExpand worked well and fast.

Comment: I find that `ExpToTrig[]` is faster than `ComplexExpand[]` for this sort of thing.